# About "openni_kinect" stack

Tags: openni-kinect, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Can someone point me to a specific "openni_kinect" or similar that has already point cloud built. I was looking at "openni_nodelet.cpp" installed from source. Previously, I was looking at "openni_nodelet.cpp" installed from apt-get, it has such a point cloud already, unfortunately, because of using with eclipse, I need to installed it via version control (from source).  Is there any?

-alfa-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10832/about-%22openni_kinect%22-stack/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-08-06**:
What I mean by "point cloud built" is there is such a functionality that I can extract and manipulate data based on X, Y, Z in cartesian coordinate(preferably)..

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-08-06**:
Can you explain what you mean by having a "point cloud built"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but you can checkout the openni_camera package using mercurial from: https://kforge.ros.org/openni/openni_ros

---

Originally posted by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) with karma: 1071 on 2011-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-02**:
miguel prada's answer is correct

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-08-05**:
Unfortunately, this one doesn't offer/provide point cloud. Thanks anyway.